# //*[@id="gwt-uid-2423"] is getting changed every rime in selenium python2.7 chrome

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

HTML Code is ..

```
<div class="N1LCMI-ib-e" role="option" id="gwt-uid-2423" style="user-select: none;">Hotel ID</div>
```

There is one button when i click on it there are some categories to select Only one category can be selected in one time. So Id in xpath is getting changed every time when i am using Xpath of that category. below is code which i am using to select that category.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gwt-uid-2423"]').click() #select Hotel ID
```

so only 2423 part is getting changed every time.

is there any other way to go for it. pls help....

Comment: give as more as possible html cod, include buttons ancestor before we can learn to to write the css selector or path for the button.  As I know, seems your application developer using GWT which using dynamical id  is common case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the element by contained text using an XPath.

```
//div[.='Hotel ID']
```

Comment: Thanks all, JeffC- it worked for me Special thanks to you..very simple code easy to understand. One more problem i have with same page where there is filter button for that button same id is getting changed i tried your method but code is not running.

Comment: If you have another question, you should post the details in a new question so that it can be understood and answered.

Comment: JeffC Thank you so much for your quick reply. You solved my query in one go..you Awesome big thanks. now i have raised new question now pls check and suggest me the correct way.. Thank you....!!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that the `2423 part is getting changed every time` for the `id` attribute, so we can create a unique `css_selector` or `xpath` as follows:

- **`css_selector`** :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='N1LCMI-ib-e'][id^='gwt-uid-']").click()
  ```
- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='N1LCMI-ib-e'][starts-with(@id, 'gwt-uid-')]").click()
  ```

Comment: Thanks- One more problem i hv i trd your method but code is not running. it's element code is - <button class="N1LCMI-r-a N1LCMI-lg-a N1LCMI-r-j N1LCMI-r-m" id="gwt-uid-598" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-598" role="button" type="button" aria-pressed="true"><div class="N1LCMI-r-h"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span class="gwt-InlineLabel">Filters&nbsp;</span><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAECAYAAABCxiV9AAAAG0lEQVR42mOIjIz8jwszgABOCRjAKYGsAJkPAKT/IKHcRfUJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" width="7" height="4" class="gwt-Image"></div></div></button>

Comment: @HarishKumarGarg Glad to be able to help you. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement?

Comment: Thanks for advice i have raised a new question now pls check and help me. You gays are awesome really thanks.